# swift4 macos NSTextFieldの入力文字制限とイベントについて

Tags: swift, macos

NSTextFieldについて2点ご教授ください。

１．数値のみにしたいのですが、そのようなプロパティなどはありますでしょうか？
２．2つTextFieldを用意し、別のTextFieldにカーソルが移った際に、
　　元のTextFieldの値をチェックしたいと思っているのですが、
　　イベントなどは拾えますでしょうか？
　　keyUpと、cursolUpdateというのがあったので、下記のように試したのですが、
　　両方のTextFieldからくるので判別方法などありますでしょうか？

**ViewController.swift**

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var text1: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var text2: NSTextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }

    override func keyUp(with event: NSEvent) {
        print("keyUp")
    }

    override func cursorUpdate(with event: NSEvent) {
        print("cursorUpdate")
    }    
}
```

Comment: 質問の編集時、ソースコードのみを選択した状態で`{}`をクリックすると見やすくハイライトされるようになるので、次回から試してみてください。

Comment: cubickさん、ありがとうございます。どうやるか分からなかったので大変助かりました。次回からやってみます。

Comment: とりあえずcursorUpdateで対応することにしました。もし他にいい方法があればご教授頂ければと思います。